# Using Primus instead of socket-io with simplewebrtc

Tags: node.js, socket.io, primus, simplewebrtc

I want to use Primus instead of socket-io with simplewebrtc.
Can any one help me to convert the below code to use Primus?
https://github.com/andyet/SimpleWebRTC/blob/master/socketioconnection.js

Answer (score 1):

How this works is that you can pass any constructor as the `connection` property to the config, and any additional options you need. Then, all your constructor needs to do is export an object with the four methods: `on`, `emit`, `getSessionId`, and `disconnect`. For Primus, you could have something like this (I've never used Primus before, just looking at docs) -

```
var Primus = window.Primus; // get primus from wherever you want

function PrimusConnection(config) {
    var self = this;
    var primus = new Primus(config.url, config.primus);
    primus.on('connection', function (spark) {
      // spark is the new connection.
      self.connection = spark;
    });
}

PrimusConnection.prototype.on = function (eventName, function) {
    this.connection.on(eventName, function);
};

PrimusConnection.prototype.emit = function () {
    this.connection.write.apply(this.connection, arguments);
};

PrimusConnection.prototype.getSessionid = function () {
    return this.connection.id;
};

PrimusConnection.prototype.disconnect = function () {
    return this.connection.end.apply(this.connection, arguments);
};

module.exports = PrimusConnection;
```

Comment: Thank you very much @xdumaine. As per discussion with Primus team, I have to use Primus at server side as well. Currently we developed server side part using Spring-websockets which internally uses SockJS. So primus team told it will not work with SockJS. So I am going to  modify above code to use sockjs-client.